# Django count number of records per day

Tags: django

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I am preparing data to show on a graph in template. I want to fetch number of records per day.

This is what I'm doing

```
qs = self.get_queryset().\
        extra({'date_created': "date(created)"}).\
        values('date_created').\
        annotate(item_count=Count('id'))
```

but, the output given is

```
[
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1},
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}, 
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}, 
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}, 
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}, 
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}, 
    {'date_created': datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), 'item_count': 1}
]
```

Here data is not grouped and same date is returning repeatedly with count as 1

Comment: There is similar question to your question, You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154227/django-orm-group-by-day?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I tried that, still same output

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TruncDate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/functions/datetime/#TruncDate) function.

See that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218987/django-count-group-by-date-from-datetime#44633870)

Comment: `TruncDate` returns `None`